# Canvas preview for Heroku

Tags: android, facebook, canvas, heroku, ionic-framework

1. I am trying to preview https://apps.facebook.com/haz-app/ but its not displaying.
2. Facebook login is not working at http://haz.heroku.com
   or http://localhost:5000, however, its working locally using ionic test at http://localhost:8100/

Github files: https://github.com/asimkh/apps/tree/haz/

check below setting in FB.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook
[image]

In the canvas there is no preview, i add heroku config vars e.g.

```
 heroku config:set FACEBOOK_APP_ID=133333333463066  \
                  FACEBOOK_SECRET=a7244e333333333a7a2bf9492a6089a0
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Facebook loads canvas apps into the iframe by issuing a POST request to your canvas URL. Looks like your app does not handle a POST request to `http://haz.herokuapp.com/` correctly, and replies with a 404 and the text “Cannot POST /” only.

Comment: any idea how i can resolve, any tutorial?

Comment: Still Errors.... Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Comment: And you get that error – when? If it happens on login – then go fill out the Valid Oauth Redirect URIs field under Settings>Advanced.

Comment: i fix login but canvas preview for facebook is not working

Comment: What do you mean by “canvas preview”?